# how to add custom url to sitemap in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a directory listing custom page for my WordPress website, http://arun.dealsinall.com/find-code, when we select state/city/town url update automatically, please tell me how can I add these all url to sitemap,

e.g. http://arun.dealsinall.com/find-code/haryana

http://arun.dealsinall.com/find-code/haryana/kernal

Means every url automatically add to sitemap.

Comment: are you using any plugin for building dropdown and if you are share that info please..

Comment: no i don't use any plugin, i make a custom page with custom code

Comment: then you have to share php code for pages that you have for that pages, we can't know how to help you if you don't show them to us..?

Comment: hi @oserk please see the code i'm updated